# Was "book" to "beek" as "foot" is to "feet"?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, old-english, i-mutation

"Foot" is a curious word in English because it is pluralized in an unusual way; the "oo" in the word is changed to "ee".  Did this once use to be a standard way of pluralizing things in English (or a language that contributed to English), which would mean that the plural of "book" was "beek" instead of "books"?  Or, is "feet" just a one-off?

Comment: Have a look at the [i-mutation](http://www.etymonline.com/imutate.php)

Comment: It's down to something called [i-mutation](http://www.etymonline.com/imutate.php) that happened in Old English. Other examples are *tooth-teeth, goose-geese, louse-lice, mouse-mice.*

Comment: @Em1 I don't quite understand, from that link, how the mutation happened with "feet".  Did the plural of "foot" used to be "foots" and that somehow became "feets" and then "feet"?

Comment: @Jez foot/footiz (or something along those lines) > foot/f**ee**tiz > foot/feet

Comment: Of course, and moose, meese {that is a joke].

Comment: @Lambie - And then there’s *box* and *boxen*!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Whenever you find an O (or some other back vowel like A or U) in one form of an English word and an E (or some other front vowel like Æ or I) in the corresponding place in another, you have two suspects to interrogate.

1. If the two words are not from the same language, but from two separate Indo-European languages, like Latin and Greek (e.g, ***ped**-al* from Latin and ***pod**-iatrist* from Greek, both roots meaning 'foot' — the *p ~ f* and *d ~ t* alternations are [Grimm's Law](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/GrimmsLawCognates.pdf) in action), then what you're seeing is ***E–O Ablaut***. Proto-Indo-European often alternated between an "E-grade" and an "O-Grade" form for morphology, and various daughter languages inherited various words. Sort of like the distribution of family furniture when the parents die. That's not what happened here, however.
2. If the two words are from English, and not borrowed, then what you're seeing is ***Umlaut***. This term refers to changing a **back** rounded vowel [o, u] to the corresponding **front** rounded vowel [œ, y] in anticipation of a front vowel [i, e] in the next syllable. This is a common Germanic feature, and is still productive in German, where there are special vowel symbols (**ü, ö, ä**, called U-umlaut, O-umlaut, and A-umlaut) that represent this phenomenon, and these sounds. Umlaut is the guilty suspect.

In English, this happened to many normal plurals because of the E in the regular plural suffix *-es*. That E was **pronounced** in Old English and Middle English, but not in Modern English; however the root vowel had been changed already and is maintained in some, but not most, of the nouns.

The original Old English (or possibly Proto-, West, or Low Germanic) of *goose/geese* (in Modern English [gus/gis]) was [go:s/go:ses]. There were several steps in the derivation:

- starting words: [go:s/go:ses]
- final s going silent ⇒ [go:s/go:se]
- fronting the o: to œ: by umlaut ⇒ [go:s/gœ:se]
- derounding œ to e ⇒ [go:s/ge:se]
- final e going silent ⇒ [go:s/ge:s]
- Great Vowel Shift raising all long vowels one notch ⇒ [gu:s/gi:s]
- long vowels become short ⇒ [gus/gis]
- ending words: [gus/gis]

---

**Edit:**
In this medium, where writing and typography has to express speech and sounds, I use italics and boldface like this:

- I use plain italics **only** for citing examples and titles. **Never** for emphasis.
- I use boldface for emphasis. These are words that would be **LOUD** in my speech.
- I use bold italics for technical terms, usually with capitals, and links if I have them.
- I also use bold italics in examples to point out individual parts that get mentioned in the text.
- Like all linguists, I use

  - **[ˌskwɛɹ'bɹækɨts]** (square brackets) for phonetic data,
    distinguished from
  - **/'slæʃəz/** (slashes) for phonemic transcriptions.

Comment: The original OE for *goose: gōs,* had plural *gēs,* at least according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gos#Old_English).

Comment: A very well detailed explanation, expressed in terms that can be understood without the need of lots of prior knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterShor: That's ***an*** original OE for _goose_. That would be after it had changed to [go:s/ge:s]. In that dialect (and there were a lot of them; there still are).

Comment: @John Lawler: How do we know there wasn't a vowel change in Proto-Germanic, which was retained in German (Gans/Gänse) and some dialects of OE, and which survived into Modern English?

Comment: @PeterShor: Whenever it happened, it happened before ModEng; the PGmic/WGmic/LGmic/AngSax/O/M/ModEng dates didn't get posted on the calendars everywhere. And for most of the rules, the order doesn't matter much.

Comment: The timing doesn't matter at all, except that presumably the vowel change developed before Proto–West Germanic split into Old English, Old High German, and Old Dutch, since all these languages had it.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I assume this answer indicates the origin of gosling too?

Comment: Sure. It's exactly like _duckling_; _-ling_ is a Germanic diminutive suffix. It occurs in many German dialects and is related to the diminutive suffixes _-l_ of Yiddish /beygl/ (_bagel_) and the _-lein_ of German _Fräulein_ (lit, 'little woman'). Diminutives of domestic animals almost always refer to young.

Comment: Had the Anglo-saxon plural _béc_ survived, it would probably appear in modern English as _beech_ rather than _beek_.

Comment: The final step in the derivation here is somewhat inaccurate: the loss of long vowels is a phonological change, not a phonetic one, but [phonetic notation] is used. Phonetically, the vowels in ‘goose/geese’ are still both long.

Comment: Vowel length no longer being distinctive, I didn't include it; I also didn't indicate the front and back variants of [g]. "Phonetic notation" is only intended to present the required level of detail, like changing the lens on a microscope; in practice, it can't represent the level of detail that a recording can, and it isn't used to do that, but to present certain details.

Comment: Incidentally, @PeterShor, we know this wasn’t PG since fronting of /a/ to /æ/ did not happen with nasal vowels or before nasals in Anglo-Frisian, though it did (later on) in German. In PG, the word was still _*gans-_, with a nasal present, and this developed regularly into ON [ɡɑ̃ːs] (written _gás_) and West Germanic [ɡɑ̃s]/[ɡɔ̃ːs] with compensatory lengthening, but Proto-German [ɡans]. Only after the nasality of the vowel was lost in WG (yielding [ɡɔːs], later raised to [ɡoːs]) did i-umlaut take place. If it had been earlier, the plural would have been _*goose_ as well.

Comment: Just noticed this now: I think you're conflating two plural suffixes here. The umlauting suffix is inherited PG _-iz_ (< PIE _-es_), whose final sibilant was lost in West Germanic, and the final vowel some time before ‘classical’ Old English, after it caused umlaut. The Modern English _-s_ suffix only became _-es_ during late Old and early Middle English—it is the Old English suffix _-as_ (< PG _-ōs_) found in strong _a_-stem masculines (the largest group), which is why it never caused any umlaut. Those that have umlaut are the last remnants of the original _-es_ > _-iz_ > _-Ø_ group.

Comment: "*final **s** going silent ⇒ [go:s/go:se]*" — Final s or final e?

Comment: The derivation starts with [go:s/go:ses]. The final -s is the plural suffix.

Comment: John, Peter and Janus: I need recommendations (please) for a textbook or "brief history of ..." type review, because I've picked up a lot of these things over the years but don't have a reference to hand to consult; I would like to study a bit more but not do a second degree, as a guide to what I'm looking for. It's fine with me if you recommend your own work(s), btw!

Comment: The best book to read is Larry Trask's _[Historical Linguistics_](https://books.google.com/books/about/Historical_Linguistics.html?id=FWFyQfMhiyQC). Got everything and very easy to read, with lots of examples and great exercises.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try to find a copy. There appears to be a revised edition; should I seek out the original?

Comment: @WillCrawford I think the revisions maintain his original prose and just add examples. His book is unusually well-written; it feels like one of those lectures that raise questions in one's mind in every paragraph, only to answer them in the next, as if the author knew what you were thinking. Very satisfying to read, and explains things very clearly. Plus good historical coverage of the growth of the field, and a lot of Basque examples and problems (the author was a Vasconist).

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks! I actually started reading _Why Do Languages Change?_ first, and like Goldilocks I'm still reading it! It's wonderful stuff, only I find I can't binge or I forget all the details and end up re-reading. His explanations of pronunciation changes are so lucid, it's ... I'll end up repeating myself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really bummed I never met him. He would be a good guy to have a pint with.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a quote from the Old English [dictionary](http://home.comcast.net/~modean52/oeme_dictionaries.htm):

> bóc [] f (béc/béc) 1. a book, a document, register, catalog; 1a. a
>   legal document, (1) a bill of divorce; (2) a charter; (3) a title
>   deed; (4) conveyance; 2. a book, volume, literary work, pages; main
>   division of a work;

Let's now look at:

> fót [] m (-es/fét) 1. a foot; 2. the foot, the foot of a man

So, I guess yes, we can say that at least the word from which  modern `book` evolved had plural in the same form as the word from which modern 'foot' evolved. I guess, as early of Middle English period, "book" lost its irregular plural, since Chaucer used `bookes`.

It's also interesting to notice that *fót* actually had an alternative form *fótes*, but this form has not survived.

Comment: Consider that German has Buch / Bücher (Plural with Umlaut). But Wort has a double plural: Wörter / Worte (with different meanings), i.e. it has a plural with Umlaut and a plural without Umlaut. So probably both kinds of plurals were wide-spread in different Germanic languages.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Online Etymology Dictionary this is an instance of [I-Mutation](http://www.etymonline.com/imutate.php)

> I-MUTATION (also known as "i-umlaut") is the raising and fronting of a root vowel in anticipation of "i" or "y" sound in a suffix.
>
> Other examples of noun plurals that exhibit I-Mutation are
>
> man → men
>   tooth → teeth
>   goose → geese
>   louse → lice
>   mouse → mice
>
> I-mutation is caused by the very human habit of laziness: taking the shortest distance between two points. The plural of man in ancient West Germanic, the ancestor of Old English, used to be a word something like *manniz. The speakers "cheated" on the first vowel in the word to be in position for the second vowel. It's the same thing you do with doing. It doesn't change the meaning of the word to do so.

So, it comes from the old Saxon roots of English. *Book*, being a relatively new and uncommon noun compared to *foot*, probably wasn't shortened so commonly.

Answer (score 7):

As a rule, morphological irregularities of Modern English are remnants of previously regular processes of Old English.

So, if English had been a more conservative language, we would have retained *beech* as the plural of *book*.  Moreover, we would have had *book* as the past tense of *bake* (like *took* and *shook* from *take* and *shake*).

German, which is more morphologically conservative than English, still has vowel alternation in both these places.  The plural of *Buch* “book” is *Bücher*, and the past tense of *back-* “bake” is *buk* (though a regular form, *backte*, is emerging, just like English *baked*).

Answer (score 6):

This will be a short answer, because I cannot research the topic right now.

I don't know whether in Anglo-Saxon times *book*, or better its equivalent, might have had a plural form similar to the one *foot* has nowadays. What I know from reading Chaucer's "Canterbury Tales" (14th century English) is that at that time the word was spelt *"bookes"* in the plural, as you can read in the passage about the Oxford Cleric :

> For hym was levere have at his beddes heed
>       Twenty bookes, clad in blak or reed,
>       Of Aristotle and his philosophie ...

Besides, the plural form in double *'e'* is surely not a one-off as you suggest; the same is true for  *tooth - teeth* and *goose - geese* (and perhaps something else which does not come to my mind right now).

Finally, we should remember that there are words which are written with two *o*'s but the corresponding verb is written with two *e*'s (for example, *blood* and *to bleed*)

Comment: That does nothing say about why the plural of book became books, while the plural of foot became feet.

Comment: @Em1. That's true, but actually the OP asked if that was the standard way of pluralizing words in English, and I reported that in Middle English the plural of book was *bookes*; then he also wondered whether *feet* was an exception, which is not the case, as FumbleFingers indicated as well.

Answer (score 6):

The plural of *foot* always was *feet*; we inherited the word from West Germanic, which seems to have had a lot more plurals where the vowel changed than English does today. The word for "foot" in German is *Fuß* (rhyming with "moose"); the plural is *Füße.* You see the umlaut: that means the vowel changes, just like it does in English. The word for *book* in German is *Buch*; the plural is *Bücher*, so you see the vowel changes in that as well. Somewhere along the way, English lost the irregular plural of *book*, and most of the other vowel-changing plurals as well. Only a handful in very common words survived.

Comment: What does "irregular" mean here ... not conforming to the rules that are still active? Because in a sense, "beek" as a plural of "book" *would* have been the regular plural according to the rules operating at one time.

Comment: @LarsH: I guess I was assuming that at the time English lost the irregular plural of *book* (based on the other answers, somewhere between Old English and Middle English), vowel-changing plurals were already becoming irregular.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above are excellent but I'm adding this just as a proof that the plural of "book" was "beek" in Old English.

David Crystal writes in [The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language p19](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=Kh_RZhvHk0YC&q=beek#v=snippet&q=beek&f=false) that the plural of *book* was *bec* at one point, but it didn't survive into modern English due to analogy with so many other regular verbs.

The relevant paragraph is:

> There are a few exceptions and complications, which analysts still puzzle over, but the general effect on the language was immense, as this sound change applied to the most frequently occurring word classes, all of which had *i* sounds in their inflectional
> endings. This is why we have in Modern English such pairs as *food/ feed* (from the addition of an **-ian* verb- forming suffix in Germanic), as well as *strong/ strength* and several others (from the addition of an **-iþ* adjective-forming suffix). **Not all the forms affected by i-mutation have survived into Modern English, though. In Old English, the plural of *book* was *bec*, but this has not come through into Modern English as *beek*: the forces of analogy (p. 212) have taken over, and caused a change to the regular *books***.

Answer (score 1):

Old English *bōc* did indeed become *bēċ* by umlaut. I don't know when the *-s* form rose, whether it was already present in OE or not (*bōcas*?), but that form eventually won out. Other words which lost their umlauts include *oak* (OE *āc*/*ǣċ*) and *nut* (OE *hnutu*/*hnyte*).

Answer (score -2):

In the old languages, such as Old English and Old Norse, which are the largest sources for modern english, book was derived from Bok. As foot was from fot. Multiples were boks and fots. By speaking these words in a fast and lazy manner, as people do in regular conversation, the words eventually evolved into Beeks and beek for the plural book, and feets and feet for the plural foot. During the transition of the 13th century, the english language started becoming more organized. English kings were all speaking old french, but demanded a unification of the English language for better unity of the people to be ruled. By the end of the 13th century, beek was no longer common and had been plurilized by an "s", thus we now use books. Feet remained in common language because everyone who spoke english mention foot and feet on a near daily basis. Books were not so common to the average englishman. The words that kept the oral mutation, such as foot and feet, woman and women, mouse and mice, etc, were all words used on a daily basis by the common man of the time.

Comment: This is complete nonsense. The plural of "foot"/"fot" was never "fots". The vowel mutation came about due to a regular process, not laziness. And kings made no decrees about the organization of the English language, if they even cared about the issue at all. The language remain splintered into dialects for quite some time.