# Why didn't "spiel" get spelled with an "sh"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, german

The [pronunciation for "spiel"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spiel) allows for either "speel" or "shpeel". The "shpeel" pronunciation is significantly more common where I live (American Midwest) and I'm curious why "spiel" didn't get the same "sh" or "sch" spelling that many other words with a Yiddish influence did:

- schlep
- schlock
- schmooze
- shtick

There are [many other examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Yiddish_origin) but I don't see any other examples of the "sh" sound turning into just an "s".

Comment: Also, though there may be very regular rules for spelling/transliteration, there is always the possibility of an idiosyncratic misspelling or deliberate addition inadvertently enshrined as rule.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This seems to be a Yiddish (or German) etymology question, unrelated to English.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have mentioned, *spiel* may actually be derived from German *Spiel* rather than, or in addition to, Yiddish *shpil.*

In German, syllable-initial /ʃ/ (the "sh" sound) is written with the trigraph <sch> before <r>, <l>, <m> and <n> (i.e. letters that represent resonants), but with the single letter <s> before the letters <t> and <p> (i.e. letters that represent plosives). I think this explains why we don't see /ʃ/ represented by <s> in words such as *schlep, schlock, schmooze*. German words spelled with <st> and <sp> are generally anglicized in English pronunciation to have /st/ and /sp/ (e.g. see this question about [Einstein](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78860/pronunciation-of-einstein)).

[Yiddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_orthography#The_Yiddish_alphabet) romanization is considerably less standardized than German orthography, but in general, /ʃ/ is represented by <sh> in all contexts, including syllable-initial <sht> <shp>. There are some variant spellings used in English that have <scht>, such as "[schtick](http://www.onelook.com/?w=schtick&ls=a)" (a variant spelling of *shtick*); I didn't find any commonly used word spelled with <schp>, but people certainly might use that for non-standardized transcriptions of Yiddish words.

Comment: Also, while high German indeed uses the  /ʃp/ pronunciation for Spiel, there are dialects that pronounce it with /sp/ instead, e.g. an older version of the [Hamburger Dialekt](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Dialekt).

Answer (score 31):

*Spiel* derives from German *spielen* not from American Yiddish like the other terms you mention (boldface mine):

> - "glib speech, pitch," 1896, probably from verb (1894) meaning "to speak in a glib manner," earlier "to play circus music" (1870, in a German-American context), **from German *spielen* "to play,"** from Old High German *spilon* (cognate with Old English *spilian* "to play"). The noun also perhaps **from German *Spiel* "play, game."**

Source: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spiel)

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/spiel#Etymology_1) hints at a possible relation with the Yiddish term *shpil* from which probably the alternative pronunciation originates:

> - From the German *Spiel* ‎(“game, performance”), **perhaps via Yiddish שפּיל ‎(shpil)**. Cognate with Old English *spilian* ‎(“to revel, play”).

Comment: Of course, German _spiel_ is pronounced [ʃpiːl] with a ‘sh’ sound, so it would have made just as much sense to write it like the Yiddish words…

Comment: ***Speel or shpeel?*** http://www.balashon.com/2015/02/speel-or-shpeel.html

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: some dialects in the northern parts of Germany will indeed say "Spiel" instead of "Shpiel".

Comment: @AnoE Yes, quite a few Low German dialects were unaffected by the preconsonantal retraction of /s/ found elsewhere. Low German generally hasn't had much influence on German loan words in English, though I suppose it's possible that in this particular case, the existence of an alternative pronunciation with /s/ could be the exception to that (if it isn't just a reading pronunciation, that is).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It would not have made "just as much sense", since words that are already written in the Latin alphabet are rarely modified when they are imported into English.

Comment: @JLRishe, clearly "speel" or "shpeel" *is* a modification of "spiel". So in the case in question (that is, the relevant one) the word was modified as it was imported.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I meant that their spelling is rarely modified, because this discussion is about spelling. So in the case in question (that is, the relevant one) my point stands. Pronunciations often do become more Anglicized as words are imported.

Answer (score 5):

JOSH's answer resolves the central question posed by MrHen. With regard to similar words adopted from German into English without inclusion of an *h* in the anglicized spelling, perhaps the closest match to *spiel* is *spritz*. Here is the entry for that word in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **spritz** \'sprits, 'shprits\ *vb* {G fr. *spritzen*} (1902) : spray ~ *vi* : to disperse or apply a spray

According to Leo Rosten, *The Joys of Yinglish* (1989) there is a Yiddish-English form of *spritz*, and he spells it with an *h* (*shpritz*):

> **shpritz** (verb and noun) **shpritzer** (noun) Yinglish. From German/Yiddish: *spritzen*: "to sprinkle," "to spray," "to squirt."

Rosten doesn't list a Yiddish/English equivalent form of *spiel*. However, *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) cites the Yiddish *shpil* (derived from Middle High German *spil*) as a possible direct source of *spiel* in English:

> **spiel** (spēl, shpēl) *Informal n.* A lengthy or extravagant speech or argument usually intended to persuade. *intr. & tr.v.* **spieled, spieling, spiels** To talk or say something at length or extravagantly. {German, play, or Yiddish, *shpil*, both [from] Middle High German *spil* [from] Old High German.}

The *Eleventh Collegiate* dates *spiel* in English to 1870 and gives only one pronunciation for it: \'spēl\ . This surprises me because I have heard \'shpēl\ frequently enough to think of it as a common alternative pronunciation. Likewise the *Eleventh Collegiate* says that the second syllable of the curling term *bonspiel* is  pronounced \'spēl\ (not \'shpēl\ )—although it certainly was pronounced with a *sh* sound in Calgary, Alberta, in the early 1970s, when I lived there. In any case, Merriam-Webster thinks that *bonspiel*, may be derived from Dutch *bond* (league) + *spel* (game); this word's first known occurrence in English is ca. 1770, so it has been in the language much longer than the standalone German-derived *spiel*.

Comment: Actually, *spritzen* is used in conjunction with liquids whereas *sprühen* means dispersing a spray.

Comment: Certainly I've only heard 'Bonspiel' pronounced 'speel' here in Scotland, where it is included in the Scottish national Dictionary with 'bonspeel' as a variant spelling. A variant pronunciation on the 'ie' is also given, but I'm not fluent in such symbols.http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/bonspiel  http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/spiel

Comment: @Spagirl: that variant would be pronounced "bonspell".

Answer (score 2):

Any discussion of English *spiel* should disregard Yiddish, which is irrelevant to its etymology. The word comes solely from German.

For details, see pages 563-570 of David L. Gold's *Studies in Etymology and Etiology (With Emphasis on Germanic, Jewish, Romance, and Slavic Languages)*.