# When we will use soft and hard sound in 'c'?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, phonetics

Sometimes we use the soft sound, and sometimes the hard – but why? Is there any rule?

Comment: I think this is a question better suited to [ELL.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What is ELL.S.E

Comment: Check the link. It's the site for people learning English

Comment: @AndrewLeach Too bad we don’t have a migration path.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Maybe this _would_ be better on ELL vs ELU, but I'd still hope the O.P. would do some basic research first. Typing `"how to pronounce c in English"` into Google returns millions of hits, and many of them – like [this one](http://esl.about.com/od/speakingintermediate/a/hardsoftcg.htm) – would answer this question just fine.

Comment: Oh, by the way, "soft" and "hard" are not good terms for sounds. They're very impressionistic, and different people use them different ways. The correct term is the sound: /k/ versus /s/, for the most part. Neither is "harder" or "softer" than the other; it's much better not to make up technical terminology.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_C

Answer (score 3):

As I've had occasion to say before,

> *English spelling does **not** represent English pronunciation.*

Consequently the letter C can represent
 - the voiceless alveolar sibilant /s/, as in *pace* /pes/
 - the voiceless velar stop /k/, as in *caucus* /'kɔkəs/
 - (as part of CH) the voiceless palatal affricative /tʃ/, as in *church* /tʃərtʃ/

as well as other sounds, depending on where their spelling has been borrowed from.

There **are** etymological rules for pronunciation,

> ***BUT*** ...
>
> these rules require one to be able to recognize English words borrowed from Latin and Greek, and to distinguish them from English words that come directly from Germanic words. It also requires one to be able to rewind [past sound changes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GreatVowelShift.pdf) and [reinsert consonants and vowels](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299) that have disappeared in speech. This amounts to studying the history of the language, which is highly recommended and highly rewarding, but is very complex and takes many years to master.

So most people don't ever learn them, and get frustrated at spelling instead.

Once you have, however, you'll see that (if you avoid "CH"), "C" gets pronounced like /s/ before I and E, and like "K" before other vowels. "SC" is /sk/ unless it's a borrowed Italian word with "SCI", which is pronounced like *she*.

Comment: Things like *conscience* — and *delicious* and *efficient* and all the rest like those — we got from French, not Italian. And then there’s *scythe* and *scion*.  On the other hand, nobody fesses up to the origins of *luscious*.

Comment: And _scent_, _scene_ and _scintillate_. I don't think it's helpful to treat "SC" as a special case, though there are some particular words which are (including _sceptical_ in British English).

Answer (score 2):

Phonetically, the letter *c* usually takes a hard sound when it comes before back vowels (*a*, *u* and *o*): car, coal, collect, calendar, curtain; and soft when it comes before the front vowels (*e*, and *i*); ceiling, cinder, circuit, certain.

Its not fair to name a few exceptions and say there are no rules. There are rules, and a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly there is a rule: the rule is to do so whenever the Dictionary tells you to, of course!

Beyond that. . . .

Once you [***c**onsider **c**oelacanth* and ***c**zar*, ***c**hemist* and *non**c**halant*, ***c**hurch* and *ar**c**ing*](http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/english-pronunciation.html), you will understand why the Poet says that *“my advi**c**e is to give up”*.  — Dr. Gerard Nolst Trenité

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: @Zafor: In that sentence, each of the _c_'s are making a different sound, sometimes on their own, and sometimes in conjunction with the adjacent _h_. When you consider _arching, aching, acing,_ and _arcing_, you realize there's not much rhyme or reason about how to pronounce words in English – at least, "fixed rules" are few and far between. The poem in the link talks about, not just _c_, but many of the other oddities in English pronunciation, like _ow_, _oo_, _ou_, and _ough_. One rule I will give, though: at the end of a word, a _c_ by itself (no _h_ or _e_) will be hard, as in _public_.