# confusion about the 'ch' sound

Tags: etymology, prefixes, pronunciation-vs-spelling, syllables

i am confused about using the "ch" as there are three sound starting with "ch" as-/k/sound, and like these. is there some important rules to find out word formation?.someone please help me.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. "ch" is not a sound. You probably want to know about the various ways the combined letters "ch" can be pronounced. Give examples of words, and say how you think they are pronounced and if you have looked in a dictionary or listened to them (you can listen to words on [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org) or the free [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com).

Comment: I've discussed this [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111032/15299) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90128/15299), not to mention [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106725/15299).

Answer (score 1):

In English, orthography (spelling) is determined by etymology (the origin of the word) rather than phonology (the pronunciation), though there are limits to which sounds a spelling can represent. For instance, in most words that come from Latin or Greek, but *not* via French, words spelled with a ch a pronounced by Americans with a hard k sound. But this can be very complicated - the same word, schedule, is pronounced differently by Americans and British English speakers.