# Pronunciation of CH

Tags: pronunciation

Why is ch pronounced as "Q", as in choir, and are there any other instances where ch is used as the letter "Q"?

Comment: [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=choir) explains it pretty well

Comment: Note that "ch" here on its own is pronounced /k/. It is the following letters that adds the /w/ sound to make /kw/, which is one of the sounds that the letter "q" makes. (Interestingly, the other sound that "q" on its own makes is /k/, as in "antique"). So there are no instances of "ch" on its own being /kw/, but plenty where "ch" is /k/.

Comment: Related (use of Q for CH) ... modern transliteration of Chinese.  Now we write *Qin Dynasty* and not the old way *Chin Dynasty* ...

Comment: One assumes you're talking about English spelling, not Pinyin. In English, Q and K are always pronounced alike, as /k/. C and CH are sometimes pronounced /k/, too. This post explains [the situation with C](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106725/15299), and this one explains [the situation with CH](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111032/15299).

Comment: @nxx It's not the letters following that adds the /w/ sound, no other 'cho' words that I can think of are pronounced /kw/, and the only other 'choi' word (choice) is pronounced with a soft 'ch'. The answer seems to be in msam's link, that it came from the French *cuer*. So it seems reasonable to suppose that any other words derived from French 'cue' words would be pronounced /kw/, maybe in the middle of a word rather than the beginning. But I can't think of one.

Comment: @Mynamite " It's not the letters following that adds the /w/ sound" - I'm not sure what you mean. Definitely there's a /kw/ sound, but the /w/ is not from "ch" -  "ch" on its own can be /k/ but not /kw/. It's only because of the rest of the word "choir" that we get /kw/ at the beginning. Now I am also trying to think of French *cue*-derived words!

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary offers this derivation of _choir_: "c.1300, _queor_ "part of the church where the choir sings,' from Old French _cuer_, _quer_ 'choir of a church (architectural); chorus of singers" (13c., Modern French _choeur_), from Latin _chorus_ 'choir.' Meaning 'band of singers' is c.1400, _quyre_. Respelled mid-17c. on Latin model." So it's pronounced like "quire" because it was earlier spelled _queor_ or _quyre_, and it is spelled with a ch now because unnamed people in the 1600s respelled it on the Latin model. The Latin _chorus_, by the way, derives from Greek χορος.

Comment: No other common English words begin with _cho-_ and are pronounced like _qu-_ or _kw-_. However, at least one _co-_ word matches this pattern: _coiffure_, together with its ministers, _coiffeur_ and _coiffeuse_, and (in some pronunciations) its root word, _coif_. These words came to us from French, and they have a Late Latin root (_coifa_), according to the Online Etymology Dictionary, but that source says that the word _coif_ is 
"of Old High German origin (cf. Old High German _kupphia_, Middle High German _kupfe_ 'cap')."

Answer (score -1):

There are many examples of words where ch is pronounced /k/ including chemistry, character, chaos, mechanic, technology, anchor, Christ, stomach and so on.

The "ch" in classical Greece was pronounced as a voiceless velar plosive, which is the sound you mentioned, so this is an older linguistic form of the "ch" pronunciation that pre-dates the sounds we more often apply to the characters today (as in "chill").

Comment: None of these have the "kw" sound that appears at the begining of choir, though.

Comment: "School" is the closest thing that I can think of off the top of my head, though that doesn't quite match either.

Comment: "Schedule"doesn't either.

Comment: Good point. Depends who you ask ...