# A linguistic term

Tags: meaning, linguistics

I have come across the term **ablaut**.

I have searched many dictionaries, however, I haven't been able to understand its meaning.
Can you tell me whether **the term** is the same as **vowel change** or not.

Additionally.We have in German language a corresponding term with **vowel change** ,that is ,**der vokalwechsel**

Comment: Yes, it is variation of vowels

Comment: The term you may be looking for is **_apophony_**.

Comment: I think "ablaut" is the German word that corresponds to "ablaut"... the English word is taken from German. It is a technical linguistic term in either language. Ablaut refers to a specific type of vowel change; in Indo-European languages like English and German, ablaut is found in the strong verbs like sing, sang, sung, and contrasts with the vowel change of umlaut seen in the plurals of nouns like mouse, mice.

Comment: _Vokalwechsel_ refers to any sound change; _[Ablaut](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299)_ is a specific type of vowel variation, usually of front and back vowels, and isn't really a matter of vowel change historically, whereas -- for instance -- the English Great Vowel Shift is historical only.

Answer (score 3):

*Sing, sang, sung, song* is indeed an example of ablaut, but only one kind of ablaut. There is another more interesting kind because it's more fruitful. This is shown by the words *nest, sit, seat*.
The root here is 's-t'. The *nest* is where a bird sits down. *ni* means down, the same as in the words *nether* and *beneath*. This type of vowel gradation was very productive, and is still present in North Indian languages, as in *beithna*, to sit, bithana, to seat.
I can't find a reference, but I suspect the word *ablaut* was introduced by the brothers Grimm, serious philologists in addition to being renowned for their fairy tales.

Answer (score 0):

Ablaut is defined as a change in vowel in related words or forms. The word actually originates from the German words "ab" (off) and "laut" (sound), meaning that ablaut literally means an off sound. It refers to when different forms of a word have different vowels, as in sing, sang, sung.