# Why is the plural form of "house" not "hice"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, irregular, i-mutation

The plural of *mouse* is *mice*, and the plural of *louse* is *lice*. Why is the plural form of *house* not *hice*?

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/house), the word house is already longer in the language, just as mouse and louse, so it is not because it is a foreign word (loanword).

This question was marked to be a duplicate of ["Goose"–"geese" vs. "moose"–"moose"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111728/goose-geese-vs-moose-moose) and [Why is the plural form of Moose not Meese?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338695/why-is-the-plural-form-of-moose-not-meese), but it is actually a duplicate of neither since they handle different words, and also different causes.

Comment: And why do you think "house" should break the "standard" and have an abnormal plural, vs "mouse" and "louse" instead using the standard?

Comment: @HotLicks Neither of those two questions is really a proper duplicate. The diversity one is too generic—it doesn’t answer why these three seemingly identical words (apart from the initial consonant) have different plurals; and the moose/meese one only addresses why _louse_ is _lice_, not why _house_ isn’t _hice_. They’re definitely related, but I think this one is different (and specific) enough that they’re not duplicates.

Comment: To add to the mystery of the -ouse family, the plural of _grouse_ (which is of unknown etymology) is—more often than not—neither _grice_ nor _grouses_ but _grouse_. And though the plural of _blouse_ is _blouses_, one common U.S. pronunciation treats the first _s_ as if it were a _z_, unlike with any other -ouse noun I can think of (including _scouse_ and _lobscouse_).

Comment: Furthermore, we refer to "a trice" rather than "a trouse"—and I don't think I've ever heard anyone use the plural form "trices."

Comment: If you listen to the British royal family,  you'll realise that the singular of 'house' is 'hice'.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The simple answer is that you’re asking the question the wrong way about. In language, the central and most important way to inflect words is always what might be termed the ‘regular’ ones. The patterns that occur most frequently and are most flexible and applicable to the most roots. In English, the regular pluralising pattern is adding /z/ (with some assimilation and epenthesis rules). Everything else is **irregular**, including *mouse/mice* and *louse/lice*. So really, it makes more sense to ask why those aren’t *mouses* and *louses* in the plural.

If we look at it from a slightly more abstract angle and ask why these three words who are identical in the singular (except for the initial consonant) are different in the plural, we can answer it more usefully.

Let’s start with *house(s)*. The reason why the plural of *house* is *houses* is that that ending is the regular pattern.<sup>1</sup> That simple. In earlier stages of English, *house* had different plurals; but it was regularised to fit in with the most basic pattern of adding /z/. If we go back to Old English, the word was *hūs* (pronounced /huːs/, like ‘hooce’ in Modern English), and the plural was also *hūs*.

*Mouse* and *louse* were similarly *mūs* /muːs/ and *lūs* /luːs/ (like *moose* and *loose*) in Old English, but their plurals were *mȳs* /myːs/ and *lȳs* /lyːs/, respectively.

So why this difference?

Well, *hūs* is a **neuter noun** in Old English, while both *mūs* and *lūs* are **feminine nouns**. V0ight’s answer has already mentioned *i*-mutation (also known as *i*-affection), which is the historical cause of the different vowel in the plural of the latter two words. Historically, in [Proto-Germanic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language), the plural ended in *-iz* (pronounced much like ‘-eez’ would be in English), and the high front vowel /i/ in that ending caused the preceding vowel to assimilate, to become more ‘ee-like’. And an /u/ that becomes more ‘ee-like’ almost always becomes /y/, as indeed it did in English. At some pre-English point in time, this final syllable was lost, but the change it had caused in the preceding vowel remained.

But this ‘ee-like’ plural ending was only used in the masculine and feminine genders; not in the neuter. In the neuter, there were various other ways of forming a plural, including not adding an ending at all. We can see from various comparative evidence that an earlier form of *hūs* also had an extra syllable lost by the time of Old English, but in *hūs*, the vowel in that extra syllable was an /a/, not an /i/ (Proto-Germanic **hūsa-* was an [*a*-stem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/h%C5%ABs%C4%85), so its plural would have been **hūsō*). Since there was no /i/, there was nothing to cause the *i*-mutation and change the /ū/ to /ȳ/.

So if we take it chronologically, starting from the Proto-Germanic stage, the development *house* and *mouse* went through went something like this (giving *singular > plural* pairs):

> 1. *hūsa-* > *hūsō* // *mūs* > *mūsiz* (pre-English/Proto-Germanic: starting point)
> 2. *hūsa-* > *hūso* // *mūs* > *mȳsi(z)* (pre-English: *i*-mutation, final syllables weakened)
> 3. *hūs* > *hūs* // *mūs* > *mȳs* (~ Old English: loss of final syllables)
> 4. *hūs* > *hūs* // *mūs* > *mīs* (late Old English: unrounding of /y/ to /i/)
> 5. *həus* > *həus(en/es)* // *məus* > *məis* (Middle/Early Modern English: [Great Vowel Shift diphthongisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) of /uː/ and /iː/ to /əu/ and /əi/; *house* starts getting an explicit plural)
> 6. *haʊs* ⟨house⟩ > *haʊzəs* ⟨houses⟩ // *maʊs* ⟨mouse⟩ > *maɪs* ⟨mice⟩ (Modern English: diphthongisation continued to /aʊ, aɪ/; alternative plurals of *house* disappear, leaving just one, regular plural)

If we focus on steps 3 and 4 here, you can see that *hūs* was the same in the singular and the plural, while *mūs* had a separate plural.

It is not uncommon for words that are under-marked (i.e., have different forms that are identical) to become marked (develop separate forms to make them less ambiguous), and that is indeed what happened to *hūs* here: people started applying the standard pattern of adding *-es* or *-en* (another formerly very common ending) to make it clearer that it’s a plural. That wasn’t (as) necessary for *mūs*, though, since the singular and plural forms were actually different there.

It does sometimes happen that a regular word becomes irregular if there is enough pressure (for example, *dive* has developed the past tense *dove* in American English because of the similarity to *drove*, *strove*, *throve*), but it is much, much more common that unpredictable, irregular forms are lost in favour of regular forms—so if anything were to happen in future to make the three words in this question the same, the expected development would be that *mouse* and *louse* become *mouses* and *louses*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The *ending* is regular; the form as a whole is slightly irregular, since the stem-final consonant /s/ is most commonly (though not consistently) voiced before the plural ending. This is a pattern found with many words that end in unvoiced fricatives (/f θ s/); cf. *mouth* /maʊθ/ ~ *mouths* /maʊðz/, *life* /laɪf/ ~ *lives* /laivz/. For all three consonants, though, the plural voicing is sporadic and only happens sometimes—there is no rule.</sup>

Comment: Noyce answer!!!

Comment: Well done. One thing that I don't understand: in the proto-Germanic why does Wiktionary say that plurals ended in *-iz* while you're omitting the *-z*? Is the '-z' something that phoneticians can't agree upon, in the sense that sometimes plurals ended in '-i' while other times they ended in '-iz'?

Comment: @V0ight Oops, good point. I don’t think there’s any doubt or lack of consensus that these words has plurals in _-iz_ in Proto-Germanic—I just changed my mind halfway through about whether I wanted to give simple nominative plural forms (like I ended up doing for _hūsō_), or abstract plural stems (like _mūsi-_). Fixing now!

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet ~ oh ok. I'm still learning as I go along and Wiktionary has been a great help, [along with Wikipedia's sound samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet General Germanic (including Old English) has lots of different plural endings beyond /-iz/. And in fact that is the least common in most other Germanic languages. There's '-er' and '-en'. The modern English plural of mostly just '-s' could easily be encouraged by Old French plural '-s' coming from Latin 2nd declension. Weird I know, but sometimes intermixing langauge influence works like that.

Comment: @Mitch The Nordic _-er_ (and I believe also the German _-er_) is actually the same as the English _-(e)s_. In German and Dutch, _-en_ has become the most common, but in English and the Mainland Scandinavian languages, the old _-as_ plural has won out. It’s not impossible that the English _-(e)s_ plural was helped along by French, but it’s also not really necessary—it was already one of the commonest endings before French influence, and its encroachment upon other endings is not unlike that seen in Mainland Scandinavia, though more complete in English.

Comment: @Mitch Also, in Latin, the _-s_ is found in all five declensions in the accusative, which was after all the case that won out in all the Romance languages. So for Romance (at least if we leave Romanian out of it), it’s almost inevitable that _-s_ should end up being the plural marker of choice.

Comment: But the plural of _house_ is not regular! Unlike _spouses_, the _s_ becomes voiced in the plural: _houzes_.

Comment: @TonyK That varies from speaker to speaker. Some say _houzes_, some say _housez_; some say _spouzes_, some say _spousez_. It’s true that that particular variation is not quite regular, but the plural ending itself is the most regular one available, and it was added on to make the plural regular. The dissimilative metathesis (if it really is dissimilative… not sure there) most likely came later than the addition of the plural marker. Added comment.

Comment: @PeterShor I’ve heard people say it both ways. My gut instinct would be that _spouzes_ is more common in BrE than AmE, but I don’t have anything to back it up with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Don’t forget to also exclude Italian from the set of Romance languages that prefer the Latin accusative plurals’ *-s* as their plural marker. Figuring out the underlying patterns or reasons in the [various irregulars](https://www.cyberitalian.com/en/html/gra_na.html) is half the fun.

Comment: @tchrist The Italian state of affairs are actually more satisfactorily explained by assuming that their plural endings also come from the accusative (albeit with some interplay from lingering nominatives). I've heard that the same is true for Romanian, but I left it out because I don't know nearly enough about Romanian to be able to say.

Answer (score 12):

*house* comes from Old English/Old Saxon *hūs* and *mouse* comes from Old English/Old Saxon *mūs* (pronounced like the animal *moose*), but only the latter experienced the phenomenon known as "i-mutation", where the /u/ sound shifts to an /i/ [then eventually becoming /aɪ/] sound when the noun becomes plural as a shortcut in pronouncing it faster.

So *mice* used to be pronounced /my:s/ in Old English (similar to the ending sound of the word *few*), before the /y:/ changed to /i:/ in Middle English (similar to modern facetious pronunciation of plural *meese* for the animal *moose*) and then to /aɪ/ in late Middle/Early Modern English, where it  eventually came to be pronounced like the word *nice*.

---

[etymonline: house](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=house&allowed_in_frame=0)

[etymonline: mouse](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mouse&allowed_in_frame=0)

> Plural form mice (Old English mys) shows effects of i-mutation:
>
> [etymonline: i-mutation](http://www.etymonline.com/imutate.php)

---

[Wiktionary on Old English mūs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mus#Old_English)

[image]

[Wiktionary on Old Saxon hūs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hus#Old_Saxon)

[image]

---

...while *house* didn't go down the "i-mutation" path for whatever reason, probably because there wasn't much need back then to pluralize *house* while *mice* were everywhere, and were much more colloquial. Think about it: how often do you actually use the word ***houses***?

---

Some English dialects even had *housen* as the plural of *house*:

[Wiktionary ~ from Middle English *housen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/housen#English)

---

Comment: is there a reason greater than/less than symbols don't show up when I use them? I had to replace them with parentheses.

Comment: They are control characters in the markup language.  I suspect you can get them to appear by prefixing with a backslash.

Comment: @Hot Licks ~ appreciated

Comment: I think the last bit of the first paragraph needs some editing. There was never an [u] in the plural of _mouse/louse_ at any stage of English—that [u] had been rounded through _i_-affection at a pre-English stage (or was the “/u/” there a typo for “/i/”?). If you're talking about Old English, it wasn't an [i] either (at least only in some dialects), but [yː]—and not with a subtle [a] before either. That diphthongisation came later, in late Middle English and Early Modern English.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet ~ thank you, for some reason I switched from the topic of plural to singular in that paragraph. Feel free to edit any existing mistakes

Answer (score -3):

It would take a linguist to give you a precisely accurate answer, and I am not one. However, I have what I'll call an educated guess.

Ask yourself how often someone from the 19th century or before would have had occasion to talk about more than one house? Not very often, I'm guessing. Particularly when compared to mice and lice. :)

Living languages are about usage, and the odd forms fall away if they're not used. There used to be a lot more strong verbs in English than there are today, but we sort of "forgot" those forms through disuse and then normalized them. I assume the same is true of irregular plurals.

As an example, think of words that end in the 'f' sound: thief, knife, hoof, wolf. Most of them pluralize with a 'v'. But there are some exceptions: roof, grief... Now ask yourself how often *anyone* (other than a roofer) has occasion to talk about more than one roof at the same time.

Comment: As a side note I have often jokingly posed the question: if the plural of mouse is mice, why is the plural of spouse not spice?

Comment: I have to object to your claim that few people in the 19th century would have occasion to speak of more than one house.  Granted, mice and lice were more numerous, but most everyone lived in some sort of town.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Why, because so many spouses are *bland*. <rimshot>

Comment: And the plural of grouse is grouse.