# oo-ee change for plurals

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, linguistics

- The plural of *tooth* is *teeth* but the plural of *booth* is *booths*.
- The plural of *goose* is *geese* but the plural of *moose* is *moose*.
- The plural of  *foot* is *feet* but the plurals of *root*, *boot*, and *toot* are *roots, boots,* and *toots*.

I have ascertained from my research that whenever an *oo* word changes its plural form to *ee*, that word traces to West Germanic. The counterexamples come from different languages.

**Questions**

1. How did these irregular nouns come to be?
2. When was an *oo* to *ee* change first attested, and why didn't the West Germanic speakers simply add an *s*?
3. Is there any significant linguistic research on this topic?

Some places I researched:

**Oxford Dictionaries**: *[Why is the plural of ‘moose’ not ‘meese’](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/03/plural-moose-meese/)*?
 **EL&U:** ["Goose"–"geese" vs. "moose"–"moose"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111728/goose-geese-vs-moose-moose)
 **SpanishDict**: *[Why moose in plural is moose, and goose in plural is geese?](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/141038/why-moose-in-plural-is-moose-and-goose-in-plural-is-geese)*
 **Quora**: *[If the plural for goose is geese, then why isn't the plural for moose "meese"?](https://www.quora.com/If-the-plural-for-goose-is-geese-then-why-isnt-the-plural-for-moose-meese)*
 [*Why is it feet and not foots?*](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-feet-and-not-foots)
 **Yahoo! Answers**: [*Why isn't the plural form of "foot" simply "foots"; just like everything else on our body? (i.e. Hand/hands)*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080103215619AAwS0Eg)
 **Wikipedia**: [West Germanic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Germanic_languages)
 **Encyclopædia Britannica**: [*West Germanic languages*](https://www.britannica.com/topic/West-Germanic-languages)

This is not a duplicate because the post in question, [Why is the plural form of Moose not Meese?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338695/why-is-the-plural-form-of-moose-not-meese), doesn't answer my question: I want to know how the oo-ee change occurred in West Germanic, and the answer on that only briefly touched on this topic.

Comment: Since you ask, [here's the answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299). This only happened to a few words; it was a long process that took centuries if not millennia.

Comment: You may also be interested in the other posts with the tag [i-mutation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i-mutation?sort=votes)

Comment: German is as close to West Germanic as English is, and these are English grammar rules I'm questioning

Comment: You may ask the linguistic site. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @etymologynerd.com: have you seen the Wikipedia article on [Germanic umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut)? I think it could be helpful.

Comment: This might be good use of the  new two duplicate feature.

Comment: @Josh, neither of those other questions go nearly as in-depth as my question necessitates.; I really don't think it should be marked duplicate. Though moving it to the linguistics site doesn't seem too bad of an idea; how do I do that?

Comment: I agree, but, most of all we have a Linguistic site for questions on like this one.

Comment: @etymologynerd.com John Lawler’s answer to the question this is currently marked as a duplicate of details the individual steps in the development of _i_-umlaut quite specifically. My own comments to his answer also help in answering your questions. Is there anything specific that you feel is not answered by that, except perhaps the bit about research on (West) Germanic _i_-umlaut (of which there is **a lot**)?

Comment: A good place to start (though it deals with Proto-Germanic rather than West Germanic) is [section 3.2.5 in Donald Ringe’s _From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic_](https://books.google.dk/books?id=ymcm0Lt9sR0C&lpg=PA123&ots=xLMmI0yjJu&dq=west%20germanic%20i-umlaut&pg=PA116#v=onepage&q&f=false).